# SQL Query with Outline and still the Plan Changes

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-performance, query-performance

This is Oracle 10.2.0.3

I have a query that has a Outline created on it.

I understand that with a Outline, the plan of execution of the query remains constant. But that is not the case.

In the last 2 days the plan has changed multiple times as seen in the plan change history for that SQL_ID.

AWRSQRPT shows 3 Different plans (Hash Values) and one of them is clearly the best but unfortunately that plan is not in USE.

What can i do to detect the root of this issue?

There are no SQL_PROFILES applied as I can see. Only 1 outline.

Is there a way to have oracle use the plan with a particular hashvalue? (that I have identified as the best)